# Autofilter VBA, How i can check if the criteria doesn't exist?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sheets is the CriteriaSheet and DataSheet that need to filter, which use the data in CriteriaSheet to fill in the Criterial argument of AutoFilter for filter data in DataSheet.

DataSheet

[image]

CriteriaSheet

[image]

My problem is, I want to know which Criteria is cannot find in the DataSheet. How do I know if the "Ant"(Criteria) doesn't exist in the DataSheet?

```
Function Filter_Function()

    Dim Data_sh As Worksheet
    Dim Filter_Criteria_Sh As Worksheet
    Dim Output_sh As Worksheet
    
    Set Data_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataSheet")
    Set Filter_Criteria_Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CriteriaSheet")
    Set Output_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")
    
    Output_sh.UsedRange.Clear
    Data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Dim Emp_list() As String
    Dim n, i As Integer
    
    n = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Filter_Criteria_Sh.Range("A:A")) - 2

    ReDim Emp_list(n) As String
    Dim R As String

    For i = 0 To n
        Emp_list(i) = Filter_Criteria_Sh.Range("A" & i + 2)
    Next i

        With Range("A1")

        ''get range before filter
        Dim rngBefore As Range
        Set rngBefore = Range(.Offset(1, 0), .Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown))

        ''filter
        Data_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 2, Emp_list(), xlFilterValues

        ''get range after filter
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim rngAfter As Range
        Set rngAfter = rngBefore.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0

        ''check whether any cells matching criteria were found
        If rngAfter Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No found " & Emp_list()
            'Exit Function
        Else
            Data_sh.UsedRange.Copy Output_sh.Range("A1")
        End If

    End With
    Data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False

End Function
```

Could you please suggest? Thanks

Comment: Why do you use a user defined function that doesn't return anything? Why isn't a [COUNTIF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) or [COUNTIFS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) function suitable for your task?

Comment: `COUNTIF` `FIND` `MATCH` ?

Comment: Actually, my use case to complicate. this function is just one part of my program.